# Complement subset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

In R, I can do the following:

```
v <- 11:20
v[-(4:5)]
```

and get  `11 12 13 16 17 18 19 20`, thus all indices *except* the 4th and 5th.

Is there an equivalent in Matlab's indexing logic?

However I wrap my mind around it, I do not seem to get the correct search terms to google my own result for this fairly elementary question.

---

Note: Of course I might use some of the set functions, e.g.

```
v = 11:20;
v(setdiff(1:length(v), 4:5))
```

However, this just is not intuitive.

Comment: Not intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Yes, it works. But is there something more elegant (and maybe more performant)?

Comment: For clarification: Does `v[-(4:5)]` remove the elements 4 and 5 or the fourth and fifth element?

Comment: Oops, yes, that is undefined in my question. It is supposed to remove the fourth and fifth element. Edited the question.

Comment: Then it's easy. See the answer by @EitanT.

Comment: Great, I just casted my first close vote. And that own my own question. Is this a good or bad sign? ;)

Comment: That's a great sign. It means that you care about keeping SO clean and helpful :) BTW doesn't casting close votes require 3K rep?

Comment: @EitanT Yes, it does. Not on your own questions, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to simply remove the elements from the array:

```
u = v;
u(4:5) = [];
```

I'm using a temporary variable since I don't know if it's acceptable to modify the original array `v` or not.

Comment: Yep, this in fact is a - actually quite obvious - way to do it. Probably the way to go. However, at the cost of an additional copy.

Comment: You don't have to use a copy, if you're okay with modifying `v` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an elegant way, but a more performant might be

```
v = rand(1,10);
sel = true(1, numel(v));
sel( 4:5 ) = false;
v = v( sel );
```